# Could not find ZenTest-4.6.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, zentest

I get `Could not find ZenTest-4.6.0 in any of the sources`

When i'm trying to migrate my database using `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

```
$ bundle show ZenTest
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.6.0

$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.9
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7
```

I have `gem 'ZenTest'` in my gemfile

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.

remove Gemfile.lock from your root dir