# Could not find ZenTest-4.7.0 in any of the sources when running Autotest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest

When running autotest, I get the error `Could not find ZenTest-4.7.0 in any of the sources`. After viewing [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767292/could-not-find-zentest-4-6-0-in-any-of-the-sources), I deleted gemfile.lock, ran 'bundle install', and then tried rerunning autotest. Now I get the error `Could not find rake-10.0.3 in any of the sources`. FYI, I am using RBENV, and I have no other problems running my app (rails c, rails s, rake, ...). Here is my gem file (btw, both "missing" files appeared in gemfile.lock):

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'

gem 'rake'

gem 'pg', '0.13.2'

# Sidekiq handles background jobs, using threading
gem 'sidekiq', '>= 2.6.1'
# Need the following gems for sidekiq/web
gem 'slim'
# if you require 'sinatra' you get the DSL extended to Object
gem 'sinatra', :require => nil

gem 'heroku-api'    # Need the API for scaling sidekiq

gem 'json'

gem 'premailer'   

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',  '3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# Bundle the extra gems:
gem 'mechanize'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'spreadsheet'
gem 'xml-simple'
gem 'faker', '~> 0.3.1'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'ruby-debug19'
end

group :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'ZenTest'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'ruby-debug19'
end

gem 'geoip'
gem 'thin'

gem 'htmlentities'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, but I think you just do:

```
gem install ZenTest
```

and probably

```
gem install autotest-rails
```

From within your application directory. 
These guys are not managed by your gemfile and bundler